# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/package_name/files/A/A.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, file, inputstream

I am using following code in android to create a file :

```
File path = new File(this.context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "A");
        File file = null;

        if (!path.exists()){
            //print log 1
            if (! path.mkdirs()){
                //print log 2
            } else {
                //print log 3
                file = new File(path.getAbsolutePath(),"A.json");
            }
        } else {
            //print log 4
            file = new File(path.getAbsolutePath(),"A.json");
            if (file.exists())
            {
                //print log 5
            } else {
                //print log 6
            }
        }
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Problem:-
When i install the APK , first time the above code works . I get the logs :
//print log 1, print log 3 .
Then i am able to get the input stream.

But next time when this code executes , it goes to print log 4 , print log 5.
But when i try to get the input stream it gives me error :
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.abc.android.abc/files/A/A.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: `Then i am able to get the input stream.`. Impossible. You just created directory 'A' and then there would already be a file 'A.json' in it? Impossible.

Comment: Your code is terrible in many ways. For instance if mkdirs() fails you even try to open the input stream. You should return then. No further execution.

Comment: `I am using following code in android to create a file :`. There is nothing in your code that creates a file.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for comments. I am aware about how to handle if mkdirs fails . But thats not the point i am asking .

Answer (score 0):

whereever you are defining f. You are defining File `path` and `file` and try to get an inputstream from `f`

Comment: sorry , f was supposed to be file . i.e InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

Comment: if you are inside log5 you should be able to get the stream. 1. try a readcheck on the file `file.canRead()`.  2. check the permission in manifest for read. 3. check owner filepermission on filesystem directly (adb)